# how to set state for different element in an array in react js

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, file

In my page 6 file pickers are used. But when I am setting state for 1 file picker it is getting set for all of them. How to avoid this problem in react js. For Reference you can see below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is because you will have a single state for all these color pickers.
You need to have different states for each color picker and you need to give each color picker a name i.e.

```
<colorPicker
   type="text"
   name="picker1"
   value={this.state.picker1}
   onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

and your onChange function will be something like:

```
function handleChange(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  thi.setState({
    [e.target.name]: value
  });
}
```

For reference : https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-multiple-inputs-with-single-onchange-handler-react